# sql + Jquery имена полей

Tags: php, sql

Делаю простой запрос:

```
SELECT 
  cars.id, 
  cars.firma, 
  cars.model, 
  cars.cost, 
  sales.sale
FROM 
  cars 
  LEFT JOIN sales 
    ON cars.id = sales.id_cars;
```

в таблице `cars` есть поле `id` и в таблице `sales` есть поле `id`.

Дальше в цикле кода когда пишу `$line['id']` берется поле второй таблицы...

`$line['cars.id']` не помогает...

Как явно указать какое поле `id` мне нужно?????

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит выложить весь код не пытаясь его упростить, потому что в вопросе не хватает каких-то данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в вопросе, явно, ошибка. Потому что в таком виде ключ `id` всего один. Но вы можете использовать оператор `AS`, если хотите получить ключ с одним и тем же названием в разные переменные. Например так:

```
SELECT 
  cars.id AS cars_id, 
  cars.firma, 
  cars.model, 
  firma.id AS firma_id, 
FROM 
  cars 
  LEFT JOIN firma 
    ON cars.id = firma.cars_id;
```

После такой выборки вы сможете получить значение `cars.id`, используя ключ `cars_id`, а `firma.id` по ключу `firma_id`. Вот так это приблизительно должно выглядеть:

```
$cars_id = $result['cars_id'];
```

Для того, чтоб в будущем избежать подобных проблем, стоит именовать столбцы в таблице, начиная с префикса, который является сокращением названия самой таблицы. Например все столбцы в таблице `cars` стоит начинать с префикса `car_`. Например так: `car_id`, `car_name`...

Comment: А если запрос выглядит       SELECT 
*
FROM 
    cars 
    LEFT JOIN firma 
        ON cars.id = firma.cars_id;

Comment: @Александр , значит, нужно его изменить на такой, как вы написали первоначально. Выбирать конкретные столбцы и изменять их идентификаторы так, как я написал в своем ответе. Еще, стоит именовать столбцы в таблицы, начиная с названия таблицы.

Comment: Принял! Спасибо, большое!

Answer (score 0):

По-моему у Вас в селекте нет `firm.id`. Там только `cars.id`, `sales.id_cars` и, следуя из Вашего вопроса, `sales.id`. Таблицы `firm` тут нет...

Comment: $line['cars.id'] не помогает

Comment: Ну, можно попробовать так: select cars.id from (SELECT * FROM cars LEFT JOIN firma ON cars.id = firma.cars_id); Но лучше так, как Вам посоветовали выше :)